# What to do when you can login to googleapps superadmin account of a previous owner of your domain?

Tags: google-workspace

I bought a domain 1 year ago. I recently decided to integrate googleapps to it. Turns out it already has an account. Since I don't have the password, I was able to reset the password by verifying the domain ownership. Now I have access to all the account (I am a superuser) and its email from previous owners.

What should I do?

Can I (should I) delete the users and start from scratch?
Notify the previous owner?
What are my resposibilities, legally or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the fact that you bought your domain 1 year ago, and only recently changed your MX records to point to Google servers for Google Apps, I would suggest that you delete all the users in the Google Apps account and start from scratch. I don't think there is a need to contact the owner since it has been over one year ago (and the original owner should have moved by then).

Of course, it doesn't harm to send a polite email to the original owner telling him/her that you are going to delete everything (since it does not belong to you anyway). If there is no reply after a week, its good to respect others' privacy and delete everything and start from scratch again.

Comment: Whats the difference between superuser and admin in googleapps? looks like I am superuser but I am not admin...

Comment: Can you post on a separate question so that more people can see it? Thank you!